# Moving selections of checkboxes from one div to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I've simplified as much as I can, but might still be best to take a look at JSfiddle first.  https://jsfiddle.net/27a8qypq/3/ I start by ticking the checkbox'European countries' on the BOTTOM box, so that Austria and Spain appear.  Now, if I tick 'Europe ONLY' on the TOP box what I want is for 'Austria' and 'Spain' labels & checkboxes to move from the BOTTOM up to the TOP box.  Note that if the African countries checkbox had also been ticked, then 'Egypt' and 'Nigeria'
must of course remain displayed in the bottom box.  I also need countries to always appear in alphabetical order, whichever box they are in.

After many failed hours on this my noobie brain's gone dead.  Can anyone help?

```
//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" id="EuropeONLY" />
    Europe ONLY
</label>

<div class="myTopBox">
    <label id="TextID" class="TextinTopBox">My European countries are...</label>
</div>
<br>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" id="Europe" />
    European countries
</label>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" id="Africa" />
    African countries
</label>

<div class="myBottomBox">
    <label class="myEurope">
        <input type="checkbox" value="Spain"/>
        Spain
    </label>
    <label class="myEurope">
        <input type="checkbox" value="Austria"/>
        Austria
    </label>
    <label class="myAfrica">
        <input type="checkbox" value="Nigeria"/>
        Nigeria
    </label>
    <label class="myAfrica">
        <input type="checkbox" value="Egypt"/>
        Egypt
    </label>
</div>
```

---

```
$(function() {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
        if ($(this).attr("id") == "EuropeONLY") {
            $(".TextinTopBox").slideToggle(200)
        }
    });
});

function sortByText(a, b) {
    return $.trim($(a).text()) > $.trim($(b).text());
}

var li = $(".myBottomBox").children("label").detach().sort(sortByText)
$(".myBottomBox").append(li)

$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    $('.my' + $(this).attr("id")).slideToggle(200)
});
```

---

```
.myTopBox {
    height: 100px;
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

.TextinTopBox {
    display: none;
}

.myBottomBox {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    height: 100px;
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.myEurope {
    display: none;
}
.myAfrica {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: While the description of your issue is clear, i fail to see what you want to accomplish with your UI. Should "Europe only" really be a checkbox, or rather a button? If it's not a button, what should happen when you un-check it? Why are the specific countries also checkboxes? Some more information on your design considerations would help.

Comment: Thanks.  As I'm sure you can imagine, for the purposes of stackoverflow I've simplified a bigger concept in order to highlight a principal  (the UI concept is about Users combining selections of regional groups with individual countries).   'Europe only' is a checkbox because when it is unchecked the European countries should move back to the bottom box, just as they were before.  The principle I'm struggling with is all about how to move those countries across the Divs.  Also, if any of the European countries are ticked, those ticks need to be maintained as they move from one Div to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [appendTo](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) to cut and paste a DOM element to another location. See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j9196uj9/) that shows how that works for your case.

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
  if ($(this).attr("id") == "EuropeONLY") {
    var targetBox = $(this).prop("checked") ? '.myTopBox' : '.myBottomBox'
    $('.myEurope').appendTo($(targetBox))
  }
});
```

What you'll still need to take care of is the sorting, but i hope the fiddle is enough to get you started.

Comment: Ah, now I realise my thinking had been completely on the wrong track.  This is great and much appreciated @czosel.

Comment: @Silverburch Glad i could help out!